# Why I am getting mysql_real_escape_string() warning?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code which inserts file names inside directory into database

```
<?php
include("db.php");

 $path = 'C:\Users\Firdavs\Desktop\Ypp';
 $directories = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new ParentIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)), 
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($directories as $directory) {
        if($directory->isDir())
          {
             foreach (new DirectoryIterator($directory) as $file)
              {
                if($file->isDot()) continue;
                if($file->isFile())
                  {
                     $filename=$file->getFilename();
                      $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                      if($ext=='docx')
                      {
                         mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Organ (Name) VALUES ('$filename')");
                         $filename=mysql_real_escape_string($filename);
                      }

                  }
              }

          }
}

?>
```

It is showing warning as following

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in Y:\home\localhost\www\jurist\import.php on line 22

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in Y:\home\localhost\www\jurist\import.php on line 22
```

But code still working, inserting file names into database;

My db.php is following

```
$con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","mypassword","jurist") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: If you're using MySQLi anyway, learn to use prepared statements with bind variables, then you don't need to worry about escaping

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` should come before the `msyql_query`, but as stated, you should use `MySQLi` or `PDO`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are mixing mysql_* and mysqli_ functions here `$filename=mysql_real_escape_string($filename);`.

There is not mysql_ connection to the database which is why you are getting this error. This is what you should be doing

```
$filename = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $filename);
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Organ (Name) VALUES ('$filename')");
```

Also ... it does no good to escape the string AFTER you have inserted it. regardless of what database api you are using.

Comment: How should it be? Please show me direction or code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using `mysqli_*`! So you need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` (with an **`i`** after *mysql*), please see the doc [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Comment: Perfect answer. I did not know it.

Comment: Apart from your escaping fail... yes.

Comment: @Sven What do you mean ?

Comment: Calling the escape function AFTER adding the string into SQL in the original code.

Answer (score -4):

You connect with mysqli function. But you are using mysql function (mysql_real_escape_string.) This is the problem. You can connect with mysql_connect if you want to use mysql_real_escape_string. But i don't suggest you to use mysql_connect. Because it'll be deprecated in php. 5.5

Comment: Don't use mysql! Depreacted as of 5.5